# Stating and proving a Fibonacci sum: $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{F_k F_{k+1}}=\frac{F_{n}}{F_{n+1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers, telescopic-series

Recently, while spending time with Fibonacci numbers, I found that
$$S=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{F_k F_{k+1}}=\frac{F_{n}}{F_{n+1}}.~~~~(1)$$
Proof:
Using a property of these numbers:
$F_{n+1} F_{n+2}-F_n F_{n+3}=(-1)^n$, we can write:
$$\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{F_n F_{n+1}}=\frac{F_{n+3}}{F_{n+1}}-\frac{F_{n+2}}{F_n}=G_{n+1}-G_n.$$
By telescopic summation, we have
$$S=\sum_{k=0}^{n}  \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{F_k F_{k+1}}=[(G_2-G_1)+(G_3-G_2)+(G_4-G_3)+....+(G_{n-1}-G_{n-2})+...+(G_n-G_{n-1})].$$
$$\implies S=[G_n-G_1]=\frac{F_{n+3}}{F_{n+1}}-\frac{F_3}{F_1}=\frac{F_{n+3}}{F_{n+1}}-2= \frac{F_n}{F_{n+1}}$$
Using another property of that $F_k f_{k+1}=F_1^2+F_2^2+F_3^2+F_4^2+...+F_k^2,$
we can write (1) as
$$S=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{\sum_{j=1}^{k} F^2_j}=\frac{F_{n}}{F_{n+1}}~~~~(2)$$

The question is: How (1,2) can be verified and proved otherwise?

Comment: What particular properties of the Fibonacci numbers are you avoiding using? I can only see two ways to show this sum: the "nice way" that you described above using properties of the Fibonacci numbers, and the "ugly way" by writing everything in terms of the Binet formula and using geometric series a bunch of times. What characteristics are you looking for in an alternate solution?

Comment: May be one can do in terms of $a,b$ by using $F_n=(a^n-b^n)/\sqrt{5}$, with $ab=-1, a+b=1.$. Induction could be another way. We don't know there may be some other surprising way!

Comment: You can simplify $\frac{F_{n+3}}{F_{n+1}}-2$ to $\frac{F_n}{F_{n+1}}$.

Comment: @J.G Oh! yes, thanks.